# ng4-autocomplete how to use it in angular 4 gives me error in console

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am using ng4-autocomplete which gives me error here is my code.

```
public list = [
    {title: 'Option', id: '1'},
    {title: 'Options', id: '2'},
    {title: 'Optiond', id: '3'},
    {title: 'Optiona', id: '4'},
    {title: 'Optione', id: '5'}
];

constructor(public autoCompleteService: AutoCompleteService ) 
{
    this.setList(this.list);
}

setList(list){
    this.autoCompleteService.filterName = "title";
    this.autoCompleteService.setDynamicList(list);
}
```

It gives me the following error in console. Please review what i am doing wrong.

**Error :** ERROR Error: Object List Found! Please provide filterName to pluck from object

here is my html

```
<input type="text" [list-length]="10" filterName="title" [word-trigger]="2" no-record-text="No Records Found!" class="form-control" id="list" [ng4-auto-complete]="list">
```

Comment: are you using this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-auto-complete) ? I'd suggest to provide a minimal running example on stackblitz, so we can have a look to the whole code and reproduce the issue

Comment: Yes i am using the following link ...

Answer (score 0):

I never used that module. bur quickly reading the documentation seems the problem is you're setting `filterName` bot in the template and the service.

I'd go to remove in the `setList()` method

```
setList(list){
  this.autoCompleteService.setDynamicList(list);
}
```

Anyway, please try to have a running example

Comment: I have also try this but still the same error i am receiving that is why add filterName in the start

Answer (score 0):

I checked the package update from `ng4-auto-complete`. They are no longer supported. Suggest to go for [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/).

Comment: ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module C:/MuhammadKamran Don't Delete/Projects/Offey-Admin/node_modules/primeng/components/autocomplete/autocomplete.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/MuhammadKamran Don't Delete/Projects/Offey-Admin/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/MuhammadKamran Don't Delete/Projects/Offey-Admin/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a shorter way of achieving it:

```
public list = [
        {title: 'Option', id: '1'},
        {title: 'Options', id: '2'},
        {title: 'Optiond', id: '3'},
        {title: 'Optiona', id: '4'},
        {title: 'Optione', id: '5'}
    ];

    constructor(public autoCompleteService: AutoCompleteService ) 
    {
         let result = this.list.map(a => a.title);//this will solve your error 
         this.autoCompleteService.setDynamicList(result);
    }
```